# How to tell eve framework to create collection name as different

Tags: python, eve

How to tell the eve framework to create collection name as different rather than using endpoint name as collection and use this collection name for post operation n etc

Is there any eve hook to do this

Best Regards 
Narendra Chennamsetty

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `datasource` keyword. Quoting from the [docs](http://python-eve.org/config.html#advanced-datasource-patterns):

> The datasource keyword allows to explicitly link API resources to database collections. **If omitted, the domain resource key is assumed to also be the name of the database collection**.

So, say you want a `/customers` endpoint consuming a `people` collection on the db:

```
customers = {
    'schema': '...',
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'people'
        }
    }
```

Other then the collection name, the `datasource` dict allows for a number of interesting settings such as `filter`, `projection`, `default_sort`, `aggregation` (see the link above)

Comment: Thanks Nicola for your answer. But Instead of mentioning static collection name  how can we dynamically change the collection name to be created before processing request?